# How to replace special characters which are present at word boundary only

Tags: python, regex

How to replace characters which are present only at the word boundary (start or end) in python?

```
a = "Hello;World;"
```

expected output

```
"Hello;World"
```

Also at later stage if I want to replace special characters only if they are present inside the word and not at boundary
For example:

```
a = "Hello;World;"
```

expected output

```
"Hello-World;"
```

Comment: what is the question exactly? I dont get it. You have a regex that does not work as expected? Please post it, sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Well `format` can handle this, of that I'm sure:

```
a = "Hello;World;"
a = "{}{}{}".format(a[0],a[1:-1].replace(";", "-"),a[-1])
a # Hello-World;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to replace a special character, whose either one side is non-word boundary,

```
\B;|;\B
```

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/07Y2uA/1)**

And in case you want to replace a special character which is surrounded by word boundary from both sides, you can use this regex,

```
\b;\b
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/07Y2uA/2)**

Comment: I like this answer as much as mine with `format`, and I wonder which is faster

Answer (score 1):

For the word boundary case, you can use the old `string.strip` with `;` argument

```
a = "Hello;World;"
print(a.strip(';'))
#Hello;World
```